# How to get out of code completion mode in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I got into a situation when using code completion in Qt Creator. I wanted to enter the line:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QStringList allIngredients READ allIngredients WRITE
    setAllIngredients NOTIFY allIngredientsChanged)
```

But because of code completion, the editor would only let me enter:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QStringList allIngredients READ allIngredients WRITE
    setallIngredients NOTIFY allIngredientsChanged)
```

(note the lower case "a" in "setall...")

How do I get out of the code completion mode so that I can correct the code?

I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1.

Comment: Why cannot you type in whatever you want? After the statement was injected in the editor do just whatever with the line.

Comment: No. It didn't work. If I changed "setallIngredients" to "setAllIngredients" then all occurrences get changed to "AllIngredients", and the program is wrong and won't compile.

Comment: I never had any problem with that not to mention not really relied on completion. If the program won't compile see what's the problem with the code names then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the Q_PROPERTY was written, you can simply hit `Escape` to exit the automatic property completion, and manually change the name of your setter.